# Keyword to use to enter in Newline in Google spreadsheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What keyword should I use to put string2 in New line in Google app script?

```
var message = 'string1 string2';
```

Comment: have you tried using backslash-n, like `var message = 'string1\nstring2';` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried but \n is also printing in output

Comment: If `message` is treated as HTML.. use HTML tags to format it

Comment: if `message` is not treated as HTML, try `var message = "string1\nstring2";`